# Find all possible child nodes of a repeating parent node

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to find all possible child nodes of a repeating parent element. For example, in the following structure,

```
<Audience_overlay>
<content>
        <Audience_code>1A</Audience_code>
        <Geographic_Location>OS</Geographic_Location>
        <Zones>
            <E1>OU29</E1>
        </Zones>
</content>
<content>
       <Audience_code>1C </Audience_code>
       <Zones>
             <I1>IN0</I1>
             <Z1>VC8</Z1>
             <Z2>VC246</Z2>
             <Z3>AF0</Z3>
             <Z4>AF0</Z4>
        </Zones>
</content>
</Audience_overlay>
```

I want to find all the child elements of zones. I.e, return E1,I1,Z1,Z2,Z3 and Z4.

Is there an easy way to do this without having to parse through the whole document as it will be much bigger than the one listed above.

Answer (score 1):

```
Audience_overlay/Content/Zones/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all nodes that match "Zones", then return all children:

`//Zones/*`